# Which component updates taxonomy Terms after rename on UserProfiles?

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, user-profile-property

I know that the `Taxonomy Update Scheduler`-TimerJob (`Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.UpdateHiddenListJobDefinition`) is responsible for updating `SPListItems` when terms have been renamed.

But...
Who or what checks UserProfileProperties for terms that have been renamed?

Background:
I have used a term as a value for a UserProfileProperty. The term has been renamed. `Taxonomy Update Scheduler` have all run, as has a full-sync of the UserProfiles. However, search still lists the old values, as does the table `[UserProfileValue]` in the database of the `User Profile Service Application`.

Now, I *could* write a small PowerShell-script to update all the values... But is there no OOTB-Feature to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... looks to me like that component does not exist.

The labels for terms used in the user profile are stored in the `UserProfileValue` database in the `SecondaryVal` column.

The only method updating that value in the database is the `WriteSecondaryValue` (in `Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileUpdateWrapperBase`). The only relevant method using this is the `UserProfile.Commit(bool)` method.

Since the Managed Metadata Service is responsible for the rename / update and it and no managed metadata timer job is calling `UserProfile.Commit()`, nobody knows that the label/name of the term has changed.

---

Let's take this example:

- User Profile: Johnny Developer
- Skills: Jogging; Reading; Swimming

The skills are terms in MMS. I rename *Jogging* to *Running*.

I have tried the following:

1. Refresh the user profile in the browser --> The field is changed right away, however the database still has the old value (and hence every other system like search); No luck.
2. Run a full sync, since the timer job at one point is calling `Commit` --> No luck.
3. I tried changing some other field in a user profile --> No luck.
4. Changed the metadata field itself --> Success!

I didn't go deeper than this, but apparently there is some kind of ChangeSet mechanism: Only fields that are changed / touched are being commited by calling `Commit`. Since the rename of the label happens in the MMS, nobody is touching the taxonomy field in the user profile, hence it is not being commited on save.

---

Apparently there is no mechanism such as the Taxonomy timer job updating all `TaxonomyHiddenList` in all site collections for User Profiles. Bug? Feature?

The best workaround I can come up with is to just update the field for all users (e.g. add a fake Skill, save, remove the fake skill)